# Pass Variables to generate PDF using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

**Web.php** I tried making a blank route to pass the $contract variables to pass the variables through to generate the pdf using dompdf

```
Route::get('/blank', function () {
    return view('sell.contractpdf','PdfGenerateController@contract')->name('viewpdf');
});
```

**contractpdf controller**

```
public function pdfview(Request $request)
{
    $contract = Contract::findOrFail(session('contract_id'));
    $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('sell.contractpdf', $contract);
    return $pdf->stream();
}
```

**In the View:**

```
<h1>f</h1>
@foreach ($contracts as $contract)
<h4>{{$contract->id}}</h4>
@endforeach
```

**ERROR:
Undefined variable: contracts**

Comment: $pdf = PDF::loadView('sell.contractpdf', ['contracts' => $contracts]);

Answer (score 0):

This should be

$contract**s**

```
$contracts = Contract::findOrFail(session('contract_id'));
$pdf = PDF::loadView('sell.contractpdf', ['contracts' => $contracts]);
```

Comment: still get Undefined variable: contracts